Animated movie with young girl and spirit world
I'm trying to remember the name of an animated anime-type movie from around 2020. There's a young female lead character who's is like the elder in charge's daughter, but always getting into trouble. They live in a large round house as a village. There's a chase scene where she breaks things and gets into trouble. She also gets into the roof a lot and hangs out.
There's also spirits and fantasy creatures, she has to go in a quest and I think there's something about spirits going to human world to live and they have to come back before they become trapped as humans.

Just to clarify, when you say it's from around 2020, do you mean that's when it was released, or that's when you saw it?
